# jqGrid upgade from 4.4.2 to 4.10 grouping issues

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Without any change to the original code I seem to have a problem with inline editing:

1. in my database the following field is varchar, but it seem that grid will not allow any text to be saved in it:

```js
{name:'Sales Text',index:'sales_txt', width:60, sortable:false, 
    edittype: 'text',
    editable:true, classes: 'red',
    cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject) {
            if (String(val).toLowerCase() == 'done'){
                return 'style="color: #999"';
            }
    },
    editoptions: {
        size:9, 
        dataInit: function(el) { 
                $(el).datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: "d M y" 
                });
        } 
    }
},
```

this field can contain a date in a format `15 Mar 2015` or a text i.e. `TBA` - there was no problem before.

2. If I try to edit i.e. 2 row in a group of 5 rows - the edit opens on the last row in the group i.e. 5

```js
ondblClickRow: function (row_id) {
    if(row_id != null) {
        if(row_id !== last_selected_row) {
            jQuery('#schedule').jqGrid('restoreRow',last_selected_row);
            jQuery('#schedule').jqGrid('saveRow',row_id);
            jQuery("#schedule").jqGrid('editRow',row_id, true, null, 
                function(){ $("#schedule").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]); },
                'xtras/schedule.php', 
                null,{},
                {},{}
            );
            last_selected_row = row_id; 
        } else {
            last_selected_row = row_id;
        }
    } 
},
```

not sure why is this happening. I tried to create a jsfiddle, but having problem making the grid read fake json data... anyway full code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/elen/5rzp3zzu/3/

P.S. not sure why stackoverflow doesn't preserve the code formatting...

Comment: The data which you included in the demo is *very strange*, strarting with outer [{}], using of `"cell"` **without any `"id"`** and so on. Moreover you use spaces in `name` property of `colModel`, which is wrong. The `name` will be used to build ids of some elements (`name:'Master by'`) and space is not allowed as id in HTML5. Moreover you use `index` property with absolute another value. I can't understand the goal of such setting and the format of data. Additionally you use `datepicker`, but you don't included JS file of jQuery UI in the demo.

Comment: I fixed it a little to the following http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5rzp3zzu/4/, but one have still many suspected places starting with rowid. To be able to edit the data you need have clean rowids, because you need to identify the original item of data and save the changes in the row(s) of the corresponding table. Moreover you wrote about "subgrids", but you use data grouping instead.

Comment: @Oleg hi. the data was a json response from the server to the grid - hence i thought i can use it as is. Yes there are no id's in the grid for cells when the grid is build `<td role="gridcell" style="color: #999" class="red" title="Done" aria-describedby="schedule_Master by">Done</td>` therefore i thought i can use names with spaces. Index i use to point out to a correct table in the query - worked fine =). The rowid does exist.. but it's not an id of the record if that's what you mean - what should've been done? Sorry i thought grouping is a part/type of subgrids..

Comment: Grouping/subgrids/treegrids are 3 absolutely independent features of jqGrid implemented in different modules: `grid.grouping.js`, `grid.subgrid.js`, `grid.treegrid.js`. **Which information you need to have on the server to identify the record which need be updated?** Do you have some column in the grid which have unique value for every row and which can be used as unique rowid? Usage of spaces in `name` is error which can produce very strange side effects. One have to fix it. Why you don't use the same values which you use for `index`?

Comment: To understand that one can't use names wit spaces you can do the following. You can open your HTML page with jqGrid in Google Chrome, copy the whole content *of the HTML code generated dynamically* starting with `<html>` and validate it in http://validator.w3.org/ (by "Validate by direct input"). You need just add the first like `<!DOCTYPE html>` which will be not copied. I'm sure that you will have a lot of errors. You can open some from my demos like [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/groupingPreventSelection.htm) and retry the same. You will see no errors. It's the difference.

Comment: @Oleg I do understand why id="" cannot have spaces. I just didn't see the grid using names as id's. anyway i fixed it on server and grid sides, but still getting rowid="null" - `{name:'ID',index:'schedule.sched_id', hidden:true, width:70, sortable:false, editable:true, key:true}` and php `schedule.sched_id as ID`... and i took the spaces out from names

Comment: See HTML5 specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.core): id ... "must not contain any space characters" and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): "The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. **The value must not contain any space characters**." See the ids of column headers or ids of input elements used during editing. All there will be build using `name` property of the `colModel`. The demo which you posted don't had any `{name:'ID',...,key:true}`

Comment: @Oleg yes i know. anyway, i do get rowid's now correctly for records that are already in the `schedule`. But for new lines i,e, `Master_by` before it is edited the `rowid="null"` - so obviously when i try to edit one of the few new lines - the grid opens the very bottom one for editing.... is there a fix i can use? the only work around i can think of - is to automatically create an ID in schedule every time a new product is added...

Comment: @Oleg updated- http://jsfiddle.net/elen/5rzp3zzu/5/

Comment: You can't work with the grid which have `rowid="null"`. You can't work with the grid, which have id duplicates or ids with spaces. Even if the web browser can display the page and it looks OK at the first glance, the page is buggy. You will have the problem with selection of rows and with editing of such grid. You have to fix the problems with ids before all. jqGrid **must** assign unique id to every row of the grid. The ids will be used in all callbacks as parameters to identify the row. Do you tried to validate the dynamic HTML code of your page? How many errors displayed the validator?

Comment: If I validate your last demo (the frame with the grid) in http://validator.w3.org/ I get 172 errors. A lot of there looks like "Bad value schedule_Sales Text for attribute id on element th: An ID must not contain whitespace." You can't expect that such code can good work. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/groupingPreventSelection.htm). It has no errors. In any way tow rows have now better ids, but **multipe rows have the same id="null"**. It's bug: the page have to have no id duplicates.

Comment: @Oleg yes understood. I fixed IDs with spaces. Grid used to give it's own ids for rows if they didn't have any. i.e. 1,2,3,... - why can't it do it now?.. Also the problem with cells where datepicker is not accepting text still persist..

Comment: First of all such values like 1,2,3 will not help to edit the rows on the server. Moreover you specified by `{name:'ID',...,key:true}` that rowids mus be get from `'ID'` column. datepicker and many of jQuery methods will also works wrong if the page have spaces in ids or if there are id duplicates. I strictly recommend you to fix the problems before analyzing any other problems. Why you don't fix `{name:'Box Qty',index:'box_qty'...` to `{name:'box_qty',index:'box_qty'` or better to `{name:'box_qty'` with no `index`?

Comment: @Oleg ok i took a completely different approach and now every row has unique ID - http://jsfiddle.net/elen/5rzp3zzu/8/

Comment: OK, now it looks much better and validation shows only one error: duplicates by `1718`. You should fix it too and then start with you main problem: What is the current problem which you have with editing? You have to change `'xtras/schedule.php'` used in `editRow` to `"/echo/json/"` for example, but I don't full understand what is the current problem with editing? How I can reproduce it?

Comment: You can't edit the last row because the previous row have **the same id** `1718`. In the same way the selection of the rows works incorrectly. Only one row should be selected in the grid, but you can select both the last and the previous rows at the same time. **Working with the grids which have id duplicates can get unpredictable results and the results could be different in different web browsers.**

Comment: @Oleg it was a typo sorry. all IDs are unique. i have resolved my "not accepting text" problem by removing validation i had at server side - as it is not necessary any more.. if you post an answer something like "the problem is caused by improper us id's for row id" i will accept your answer. thank you very much for all your help! you are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important that every input item (from the server response) contains **unique id**. If you save the ids in some column then you can use `key: true` property in the column. It informs jqGrid to assign `id` attribute of every row of the grid (every `<tr>` element) to the value from the column.

Additionally it's important to use unique `name` values in `colModel`, which don't contains any spaces. The names will be used to build ids of searching field and editing fields, but HTML5 don't allows to use spaces inside the ids. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.core):

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).
>
> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value **must not
>   contain any space characters**.